# I want to use javax jms

Tags: netbeans

I want to use javax.jms in netbeans project , but netbeans tell my that there is no package like this , what should I do ?

this error occurs when I try from terminal

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/MessageListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have the `jms-api.jar` in your classpath.  I got mine from [HornetQ](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq/downloads.html).

***Edit***

I just saw that you said you were using NetBeans.  In that case, you need to have downloaded the version of NetBeans that includes Java EE.  [Go here](http://netbeans.org/downloads/) and download that.  [This site](http://dev.eek.be/2011/01/create-a-message-driven-bean-with-netbeans/) seems to have a nice tutorial on how to set it up from there.